# Centering Multi-line labels in Core Plot, iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, label

I'm working on a Core Plot project and have run into a problem.  My X-axis labels are all more than one line.  I want them to be perfectly centered and the only way i've been able to do that so far is to manually add spaces to the NSString that is the label. Please see the code below...

```
 NSDictionary *dataTemp=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:white,@"      
 White\rBuilding\r(220 max)",rec,@"Rec. Hall\r(240 max)",im,@"    IM\rBuilding\r(60 
 max)",fit,@"Fitness\r   Loft\r(40 max)",nil];
```

I would think there is a way to align the labels programmatically but I have yet to find it. I'd appreciate any help. Here's a screenshot of what the graph labels looks like

[image]

Here's the code where I define the x-axis labels...

```
//Array containing all the names that will be displayed on the X axis
dates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Rec. Hall\r(240 max)", @"  White\rBuilding\r(220 
max)", @"    IM\rBuilding\r(60 max)",
         @"Fitness\r   Loft\r(40 max)",  nil];
```

And here's the code where I make the labels on the chart

```
 //X labels
int labelLocations = 0;
NSMutableArray *customXLabels = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *day in dates) {
    CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:day 
textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
    newLabel.tickLocation   = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:labelLocations] decimalValue];
    newLabel.offset         = x.labelOffset + x.majorTickLength;
    [customXLabels addObject:newLabel];
    labelLocations++;
    [newLabel release];
}
x.axisLabels                    = [NSSet setWithArray:customXLabels];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work - you should try using the `textAlignment` property on the labels:

```
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

As @Martin noted, you could also add `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` so line-breaks only occur after whole words:

```
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

Comment: And add NSLinebreakByWordWrapping so that line breaks happen with whole words

Comment: Sorry, didn't work...I've edited my post to include more code though. I think Something is wrong with the way I am creating the labels.          When I try to do newLabel.textAlignment, it does not work.

Comment: @pj409 Try using labelAlignment = CPAlignmentCenter; and check this link out - https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/detail?r=cd1f17fc48# - make sure you click on 'expand all'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the text style used when creating the labels (`x.labelTextStyle`) includes the following property setting:

```
textStyle.textAlignment = CPTTextAlignmentCenter;
```